# Do I need dynamic pivot? or is there another way?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, pivot, case

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
Item_Id       Value      Type
 001           300       B2B
 001           450       (blank)
```

I am trying to make B2B and P2P columns so my result would look like this:

```
Item_Id        B2B      (blank) 
 001           300       450
```

So instead of taking up 2 rows it now only takes up one.  The issue is that the values are not static and I need to account for that.  Dynamic query + Pivot is slightly out of my league but not impossible.  I'm hoping I can use a case statement or some other way to work around this.... any help is greatly appreciated!

I would also like to rename blank.... also can't seem to get pivot to work for type due to that blankety blank!

Comment: Are the types Static?   If they are, then you don't need a dynamic pivot to produce the desired results.  It's just a standard pivot on Type.

Comment: agree with Tab, if yo have types static, you dont need dynamic sql. else we can write one

Comment: The types are static, but one of my types is blank =/

Comment: What do you mean by blank?  Do you mean `''` or do you mean `NULL`?  Those are different in SQL Server.

Comment: Bacon - blanks, and I think nulls would have been easier to deal with

Answer (score 1):

Try this a normal static pivot should work. I guess u need no column name so am inserting empty string.

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT '001','300','B2B'
UNION
SELECT 001,450,'' 


SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   #temp) AS p
       PIVOT (Max(value)
             FOR [type] IN([B2B],
                           [ ])) piv
```

Comment: I was making this a lot harder than needed.  I just did a case statement to create a type for the blanks and then all is well with the static pivot.  I love this site because sometimes I'm just not making the connection and need the help of the gurus on here.  Thanks everyone for helping me with this!